# Reference dll in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I am using Xamarin and I am new to it. I need to reference a dll which already uses System.Drawing due to which I am getting error. I know we can't use it because it is built aroung GDI+. 
So plz let me know what should I do to successfully refer my dll. Even if I remove reference of System.Drawing from my dll then it is getting errors as it is using Bitmap, Image,Size etc. If I have to remove System.Drawing dll then how should I resolve the errors. Is there something else that can be used instead of Bitmap,Image,Size etc.
Plz help me and guide me with simple explanation as I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

As you found out there is no System.Drawing in Xamarin on mobile. Thus you might reuse sources (I assume you have those) into android(?) library and instead of Drawing types use Android (or iOS) ones. That would require code changes though.

Comment: Can you plz suggest name of some android dll which can be used as dll in dot net with classes like Rectangle,Size.Bitmap etc.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Droid already has such classes in framework. You don't need to reference external dll's. All you need to do to start using them is using Android.Graphics; in your class.